# Is it good practice to use cascade in both ManyToMany entities with Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have 2 classed, Client and Stock (code is below). They are connected to each other with ManyToMany relationship. And both has   `cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}`.

I already tested that it works fine. I just want to know is it good practice do use 
cascade this way ?

Client class:

```
import com.sun.javafx.beans.IDProperty;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name = "client_table")
public class Client {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "client_seq_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "client_seq_generator", sequenceName = "client_seq", allocationSize = 3)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "client",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true
    )
    private List<Contribution> contributions = new ArrayList<Contribution>();

    @ManyToMany(
            cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}
    )
    @JoinTable(
            name="client_stock_table",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "client_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "stock_id")
    )
    private Set<Stock> stocks = new HashSet<Stock>();

    public Client() {}

    public Client(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }



    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Contribution getContribution(int id) {
        return contributions.get(id);
    }

    public void addContributions(Contribution contribution) {
        contribution.setClient(this);
        this.contributions.add(contribution);
    }

    public void removeContributions(Contribution contribution) {
        if(contribution != null && contributions.contains(contribution))
        {
            contribution.setClient(null);
            this.contributions.remove(contribution);
        }

    }

    public Set<Stock> getStocks() {
        return stocks;
    }

    public void addStock(Stock stock)
    {
        if(stock != null)
        {
            stocks.add(stock);
            stock.getClients().add(this);
        }
    }

    public void removeStock(Stock stock)
    {
        if(stock != null)
        {
            stocks.remove(stock);
            stock.getClients().remove(this);
        }
    }

}
```

Stock class:

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;


@Entity
@Table(name = "stock_table")
public class Stock {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "stock_seq_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "stock_seq_generator", sequenceName = "stock_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(
            mappedBy = "stocks",
            cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}
    )
    private Set<Client> clients = new HashSet<Client>();

    public Stock() {}

    public Stock(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Set<Client> getClients() {
        return clients;
    }

    public void addClient(Client client)
    {
        if(client != null)
        {
            clients.add(client);
            client.getStocks().add(this);
        }
    }

    public void removeClient(Client client)
    {
        if(client != null)
        {
            clients.remove(client);
            client.getStocks().remove(this);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: It's entirely up to you. Just keep in mind that anything not explicitly spelled out in the layer that is most touched such as your Service implementations, there could be a chance for a destructive and unwanted regression. I've seen cases where a cascading delete was destructive and kept an entire team up all night recovering the damages.

Comment: It will be more appropriate to post it here[Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). With that being said, I don't see anything wrong with it.

Comment: @FallaCoulibaly I think this question is appropriate here. It's a nuanced question (with some edits that can generalize this question) that deserves a nuanced answer

Answer (score 0):

This is not a convenient approach in my opinion.

1. `Client` (and maybe `Stock`) is a reference table. Other tables that refer to the `Client` table, as a reference table, can exist.
2. You can't legally work with join `client_stock_table` table using Hibernate. I mean, without `Client` or `Stock`.

So better

Remove `@ManyToMany` association from `Client` and `Stock` and use additional persistent class `ClientStocks` with `@ManyToOne` and `@OneToMany` associations.